# How to pre-load the data block index for HFile in HBASE?

Tags: performance, indexing, hbase, block

I want to improve the reading performance, so thinking about pre-load the data block index before any search request reached, how do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block index is pre-loaded when HFiles are opened.

The data blocks are loaded on demand.